# Retrieve records from multiple Records returned by Sub-Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, sql-order-by

I have this database Diagram :

[image]

the diagram is represent a database for Insurance Company.

the `final_cost` table represent the cost that the company should paid to repair a car

the table `car` has the field `car_type` which take one of the following values (1,2,3) where 1 refers to small cars, 2 refers to trucks , 3 refers to buses

I want to retrieve the name of kind (1 or 2 or 3 ) which has the maximum repaired cost during the 2013 year

I wrote The following Query :

```
select innerr.car_type from (
  select car_type ,sum(fina_cost.cost) from car_acc inner join cars on cars.car_id = car_acc.car_id
  inner join final_cost on FINAL_COST.CAR_ACC_ID = car_acc.CAR_ACC_ID
  where (extract(year from final_cost.fittest_date)=2013)
  group by(car_type)) innerr;
```

but I don't know how to get the `car_type` with maximum repaired Cost from the `inner` Sub-Query !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have access to anything and everything from a subquery if you use it right. The best way to build a complicated query is to start simply, seeing what data you have and usually the answer, or the next step, will be obvious.

So let's start by displaying all the accidents for 2013. We aren't interest in the individual cars, just the most expensive accidents by type. So...

```
select  c.car_type, f.cost
from    car_acc a
join    cars    c
    on  c.car_id = a.car_id
join    final_cost f
    on  f.car_acc_id = a.car_acc_id
where   f.fittest_date >= date '2013-01-01'
   and  f.fittest_date <  date '2014-01-01';
```

I've changed the filtering criteria to a sargable form for efficiency. I don't usually worry about performance early in the design of a query, but when it's this obvious, why not?

Anyway, we now have a list of all 2013 accidents, by car type and the cost of each one. So now we only have to `group by` the type and take the `Max` of the cost of each group.

```
select  c.car_type, Max( f.cost ) MaxCost
from    car_acc a
join    cars    c
    on  c.car_id = a.car_id
join    final_cost f
    on  f.car_acc_id = a.car_acc_id
where   f.fittest_date >= date '2013-01-01'
   and  f.fittest_date <  date '2014-01-01'
group by c.car_type;
```

Now we have a list of car types and the most expensive accidents for that type for 2013. With only three rows in the result set, it's easy to see which is the car type we're looking for. Now we just have to isolate that one row. The easiest step from here is to use this query in a CTE.

```
with MaxPerType( car_type, MaxCost )as(
  select  c.car_type, Max( f.cost ) MaxCost
  from    car_acc a
  join    cars    c
      on  c.car_id = a.car_id
  join    final_cost f
      on  f.car_acc_id = a.car_acc_id
  where   f.fittest_date >= date '2013-01-01'
     and  f.fittest_date <  date '2014-01-01'
  group by c.car_type
)
select  m.car_type, m.MaxCost
from    MaxPerType m
where   m.MaxCost =(
     select  Max( MaxCost )
     from    MaxPerType );
```

So the CTE gives us the largest cost per type and the subquery in the main query gives us the largest cost overall. So the result is the type(s) that match the largest cost overall.

Answer (score 0):

You could try either orderby or better yet, use the Max Function http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm

Comment: I don't want to order the results!!! I want to get the maximum value from the returned sub-query

Comment: In that case, use the max function to see if that works for you.

Comment: Ok,  In that case, add Order by desc on the sub query.  Then on the outer query use where rownum=1;

Comment: but what happen if I have two car kinds have the same maximum value ! how to return the name of these two kinds ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.car_type 
FROM (SELECT c.car_type, SUM(fc.cost) totalCost
      FROM car_accident ca
      INNER JOIN cars c ON c.car_id = ca.car_id
      INNER JOIN final_cost fc ON fc.CAR_ACC_ID = ca.CAR_ACC_ID
      WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fc.fittest_date) = 2013
      GROUP BY c.car_type
      ORDER BY totalCost DESC
     ) AS A
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: thanks! but I have a question here, let's say that the total cost for type 1 is 1000, and the total cost for type 2 is also 1000, how to return 1 and 2because they have the same maximum value ?